# Как запустить VirtualBox и Docker одновременно?

Tags: docker, virtualbox, hyper-v

Или быстро отключать Hyper-V что бы поработать с VirtualBox, а потом быстро и легко включить Hyper-V что бы поработать с Docker?

Comment: [*отключать Hyper-V что бы поработать с VirtualBox*](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/16801) — очевидное решение: не пользоваться ms/windows

Comment: @alexanderbarakin т.е. ты хочешь сказать что в Windows такое невозможно?